# Find all indexes of maximum elements in a List

Tags: c#

I have the following:

```cs
List<decimal> results = new List<decimal>();

...

result.Add(...);

...

Console.WriteLine($"Maximum gain: {gains.Max():f6} (#{results.IndexOf(gains.Max()) + 1})");
Console.WriteLine($"Maximum loss: {Math.Abs(losses.Min()):f6} (#{results.IndexOf(losses.Min()) + 1})");
```

IndexOf finds only the first index. I want to display all indexes in case there is more than one index.

Example with more than one maximum index:

```
Maximum gain: 0.000700 (#15, #44)
```

Example with one index:

```
Maximum gain: 0.000700 (#13)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'd pull the max out into a variable that can be used in a Linq query that will get the indexes.  Then use that to create a formatted string list to use in the string you output to the console.

```
var maxGain = gains.Max();
var maxIndexes = string.Join(
    ", ", 
    results.Select((r,i) => new { Result = r, Index = i })
        .Where(x => x.Result == maxGain)
        .Select(x => $"#{x.Index +1}"));

Console.WriteLine($"Maximum gain: {maxGain:f6} ({maxIndexes})");
```

Comment: Any possibility with `.Aggregate` instead of Join()?

Comment: @nop, it's "`string.Join`" I don't really see why you don't want it (I was about to post an answer equivalent to this one when I saw it)

Comment: You could do that with a `StringBuilder`, but it would be a mess as you'd have to keep track of when to add a comma.  `string.Join` is specifically designed for this.

Comment: I wanted `.Aggregate` because my top 3 query looks like this: `Console.WriteLine($"TOP 3: {results.Where(e => e > 0).OrderByDescending(e => e).Take(3).ToList().ConvertAll(e => e.ToString("f6")).Aggregate((current, next) => $"{current}, {next}")}");`. What would be its equivalent with `string.Join`?

Comment: You'd do `string.Join(", ", results.Where(e => e > 0).OrderByDescending(e => e).Take(3).Select(e => e.ToString("f6"))`.  The `ToList` just to do `ConvertAll` is unnecessary.  And note that this will not have an extra leading comma.

Comment: Some people like to create a extention method like `public static string ToDelimitedString(this IEnumerable<string> strings, string separator) => string.Join(separator, strings);` so you can do something like  `results.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToDelimitedString(", ");` instead.  Or a generic one like `public static string ToDelimitedString<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, string separator) => string.Join(separator, items);`

Comment: Thank you! :) Works as expected.

Comment: Note the other reason to not do that `Aggregate` is that you're concatenating strings in a loop which is bad because strings are immutable so you end up creating a bunch of intermediate strings that way.